# Find index of Regex matches in Linq

Tags: c#, regex, linq, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary defined as `Dictionary<int, Regex>`. There are a number of compiled Regex objects within this. This was done using C# .NET 4.

I'm trying to use a Linq statement to parse the dictionary and return an object that contains all of the dictionary Keys and the index of where each Regex was found in the specified text.

The IDs return fine, but I'm unsure of how to get the location of where the text was found. Can someone help me out?

```
var results = MyDictionary
    .Where(x => x.Value.IsMatch(text))
    .Select(y => new MyReturnObject()
        {
            ID = y.Key,
            Index = ???
        });
```

Comment: This question basically has nothing to do with LINQ or with dictionaries. It could be simplified.

Comment: `Dictionary<T,T2>`s don't have an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) property of the [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) class instead of doing simple [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx).

---

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Regex>() 
    {
        {1, new Regex("Bar")},
        {2, new Regex("nothing")},
        {3, new Regex("r")}
    };
    var text = "FooBar";

    var results = from kvp in MyDictionary
                  let match = kvp.Value.Match(text)
                  where match.Success
                  select new 
                  {
                        ID = kvp.Key,
                        Index = match.Index
                  };

    results.Dump(); 
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The screenshot: is that a default feature of VS2012?

Comment: @Alex No. The grid and also the `Dump()` method you see in my code are part of [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code based on [`List<T>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method.

```
.Select(y => new MyReturnObject()
        {
            ID = y.Key,
            Index = YourDictionary.Keys.IndexOf(y.Key)
        });
```